# Как вывести одно TV-поле в нескольких шаблонах?

Tags: modx, revo

Создал TV-поле для замены телефона в шапке сайта. Этот TV доступен для редактирования с главной страницы сайта (шаблон "Главная"). В остальные шаблоны добавил вывод этого TV: [[*phone]], но почему-то телефон на остальных страницах не отображается. Отображается только на главной. Как это исправить? Я ошибся или так выводить TV нельзя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойствах TV-поля, закладка "Доступно для шаблонов" поставьте галочки, для тех шаблонов в которых будет доступ к этому полю. Так же можно в шаблоне в закладке "Дополнительные поля" указать какие TV-поля будут доступны для данного шаблона.

P.S. Немного не вник в ваш вопрос, вам надо использовать 1 заполненое TV-поле в разных шаблонах, тогда вам лучше использовать чанк в котором вы пропишите номер, а сам чанк выводите в тех шаблонах которые вам нужны

Comment: 1. Согласен с чанками, лучше через них это сделать. Для себя так бы и сделал, а сейчас попробовал это сделать через TV. 2. Если сделать "доступно для шаблонов", то потом на каждой странице придётся прописывать номер, если его надо будет изменить? Хотелось бы ввести номер 1 раз, и чтобы он отображался на всех страницах. Если через TV никак, сделаю через чанки.

Comment: Если вам надо ввести номер 1 раз и использовать его, то лучше чанки, TV-поля немного для другого. К примеру у вас есть однотипные страницы филиалов. Вы сделали шаблон "филиал", к нему добавили TV-поля с номером, адресом, ф.и.о. руководителя. И потом на основе этого шаблона делаете страницы филиалов заполняя TV-поля в каждой странице - они уже будут выведены в шаблоне в там где вам надо. Но для каждой страницы они будут разные. Вы конечно можете использовать и TV-поле (см. дополнение к примеру PdoField: ``[[pdoField?&id=`1`&field=`phone`]]``) но это из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Благодарю! Я вас понял, сделаю через чанки. Значит, это я лишнюю работу себе придумал.

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаете ClientConfig, добавляете туда TV-поля и выводите на любых страницах через [[++name.tv]]